# Using valgrind to start a program that is started using a cryptic bash command

Tags: bash, shell, valgrind

I have the following bashscript in my `/opt/mydev` folder

```
COMMAND=""

buildCommand2() {
    COMMAND=$COMMAND"--tab -e 'bash -c \"source ~/.bashrc; source ~/Desktop/developer/setup.bash; cd /opt/mydev/$1& $1/$1; bash\"' "
} 

buildCommand2 'MyFileManager'
```

Now `/opt/mydev` folder contains a folder named `MyFileManager` which contains an executeable named `MyFileManager`

When I run the above bash script, it starts up `MyFileManager` in a new tab.

I now want to run the executeable `MyFileManager` with valgrind

```
valgrind --leak-check=full \
         --show-leak-kinds=all \
         --track-origins=yes \
         --verbose \
         --log-file=valgrind-out.txt \
         ./MyFileManager/MyFileManager
```

How do I do this? I found the `buildCommand2` quite cryptic

Answer (score 2):

i typically use an additional (empty by default) variable, that injects `valgrind` (or `gdb`; or `wine`; or...) in the right place....

for whatever reasons i call it `INTERPRETER`, but pick your own better name...

```sh
COMMAND=""
: ${INTERPRETER:=""}

buildCommand2() {
    COMMAND=$COMMAND"--tab -e 'bash -c \"source ~/.bashrc; source ~/Desktop/developer/setup.bash; cd /opt/mydev/$1 & ${INTERPRETER} $1/$1; bash\"' "
}

buildCommand2 'MyFileManager'
```

than run your script with:

```
$ export INTERPRETER="valgrind --leak-check=full \
         --show-leak-kinds=all \
         --track-origins=yes \
         --verbose \
         --log-file=valgrind-out.txt"
$ mybuildcommand
```

or in one line:

```
$ INTERPRETER="gdb --args" mybuildcommand
```

notes:

- the `: ${INTERPRETER:=""}` is effectively a no-op; it only serves to document the existence of the variable. you could use it to provide a default interpreter
- you still have to provide the entire invocation of `valgrind` (or whatver) on the cmdline; this is by design (as I usually want different variants to be readily available)
- i've just copy'n'pasted your script, even though it appears to have some syntax errors